# LiveQuery Not working working with Node.js and Oriento

Tags: node.js, socket.io, orientdb, oriento

I have made a **LiveQuery** and I don't understand why it doesn't responses when I insert something to the Class Buyers.

Here is my code:

```
function hearingQueries() {
    server.liveQuery("LIVE SELECT FROM Buyers")
    .on('live-insert', function(data) {
      io.emit('chat message', "Server says: " + data.content.message);
    })
    .on('live-delete', function(data) {
      io.emit('chat message', "Server deleted: " + data.content.message);
    })
  }
```

The function `hearingQueries()` get call when someone connected to the page:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('User connected.');
  
  server.open();
  hearingQueries();
  
  console.log('Connection succeeded.');
```

`server.open();` is a function that initiate the connection.

My questions are:

- Why this doesn't work?
- Is it better to start the server when someone connect or when the server goes online?
- If it's better to start it when the server starts it doesn't slow the server?

Here is my code so you can see exactly what is going on:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var OrientDB = require('orientjs').ODatabase;
/*if (typeof localStorage === "undefined" || localStorage === null) {
  var LocalStorage = require("node-localstorage").LocalStorage;
  localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
}*/


app.get('/indexStyle.css', function(req, res) {
  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/indexStyle.css");
});

app.get('/chat', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get('/login.css', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.css");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html");
    console.log('User has reached the login page.');
});

var msgs = [];
var names = [];
var i = 0;

var server = new OrientDB({
    host:       'localhost',
    port:       8081,
    username:   'root',
    password:   'rootPassword',
    name: 'DemoUdemy',
    useToken: true
  });

  
  function openServer(){
    server.open().then(function(){
      console.log("Server Opened.");
    }); 
  }
  
  function closeServer(){
    server.close().then(function(){
      console.log("Server Closed.");
    });
  }
  
  function insert(className, name, bucket, color){
      
    server.query("INSERT INTO "+className+"(name, bucket, color) VALUES('"+name+"', '"+bucket+"', '"+color+"')");
  }
  
  /*function select(items ,className){
    
    var msgTemp = server.query("SELECT '"+items+"' FROM '"+className+"'");
    console.log(msgTemp.Content.Data);
  }*/
  
  function hearingQueries(){
    server.liveQuery("LIVE SELECT FROM Buyers")
    .on('live-insert', function(data){
      io.emit('chat message', "Server says: " + data.content.message);
    })
    .on('live-delete', function(data){
      io.emit('chat message', "Server deleted: " + data.content.message);
    })
  }

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('User connected.');
  
  openServer();
  //select("name, bucket", "Buyers");
  hearingQueries();
  
  console.log('Connection Succed.');
  
  var iTemp = i - 1;
  
  for(var msg in msgs)
    socket.emit('chat message', msgs[msg]);
  
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    msgs.push(names[iTemp] + msg);
    io.emit('chat message', names[iTemp] + msg);
  });
  
  socket.on('getUser', function(user){
    i++;
    names[i-1] = user + ": ";
  });
  
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    i--;
    closeServer();
    console.log("User has disconnected.");
  });
  
});

http.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('Listening to Port *8080');
});
```

Comment: what module are you using?

Comment: I am using require('express')(), require('http').Server(app), require('socket.io')(http), require('orientjs').ODatabase;

Comment: what about `server`?

Comment: Server is = `var server = new OrientDB({
    host:       'localhost',
    port:       8081,
    username:   'root',
    password:   'rootPassword',
    name: 'DemoUdemy'
  });` But this works, I cant INSERT and SELECT, server.query works perfectly.

Comment: try this one(replace select and insert with actual query):
`server.open().then(()=>{..select..}).then(()=>{..insert..}).then(()=>{ server.close() })`

Comment: Yeah, actually that work. I am talking in specifically about LiveQuery.

Comment: Can you try to use the token in settings ?
http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientJS-Server.html#using-tokens
I think it's required for live queries. The docs it's not updated. I'm updating it now

Comment: It didnt work, I am going to paste the whole code so you can see exactly what I have.

Comment: Yes please share it.

BTW here it is the live query test 
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/blob/master/test/db/live-query.js